# Persistance/Spring Boot find Page and Condition Combination

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository, persistence

This is more a I dont know what to google question than a real I dont know what I want question;

I have the following Entity

```
@Entity
public class ExampleEntity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;
private Date dueDate;
...
getter + setter
...
}
```

I want to get a Pageable of this Entity out of an Repository with the following strategy shown in pseudo code:

Sort by:

> if(dueDate < 7 Days in future)
>
> then everything else sort by name

Is this possible with only one Request?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value by only one request by executing query in spring framework repository as follows. I use CRUDRepository For this purpose:

```
public interface ExampleEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<ExampleEntityRepository,Integer> {
    public List<ExampleEntityRepository> findByDueDateLessThanOrderByNameAsc(Date dueDate);
}
```

you need to call the method using the following lines of code:

```
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    current.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,7);
    exampleRepository.findByDueDateLessThanOrderByNameAsc(current.getTime())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,
I might not have been precise enough with my pseudo code; Here is a small Database model with the Date in distance notation:

`1: A : +99
|
2: B : +2
|
3: C : +10
|
4: D : +1
|
5: E : unset
|
6: F : +11`

should result in:
`___ if duedate < 7 days in future ___
4: D: +1
|
2: B: +2
|
___ then everything else ___
|
1: A: +99
|
3: C: +10
|
5: E: unset
|
6: F: +11`

Comment: this should be an union based query. you need to write native query for this